# LaTeX: How to change one of section numbers to a custom letter?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have something like this:

```
Section 1
...
Section 2
...
Section 3
Subsection 3.1
...
Section 4
...
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
Section 1
...
Section 2
...
Section A
Subsection A.1
...
Section 4
...
```

In other words - change one of section numbers to something else 3 == A
I need this for my thesis which is written in article class, and when I tried to add appendices the *hyperref* package broke, and "links" to *section 1* directed to *appendix A*

edit:
I made a mistake when describing the problem, I meant that the *table of contents* doesn't work because LaTeX generates code (*.toc file):

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}}{1}{section.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}}{1}{section.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {A}}{1}{section.1}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created the following construction, *and now updated it*:

**Description**:

A new counter for sections, which will get used only in a `\begin{alphasection}` ... `\end{alphasection}` block. Do not nest the block, or the original section number will get lost; *an error message is given in this case*. Each block will start recounting from "A". Original section counting continues, as this is required for HyperRef.

Put the following code in the **Preamble**:

```
\newcounter{alphasect}
\def\alphainsection{0}

\let\oldsection=\section
\def\section{%
  \ifnum\alphainsection=1%
    \addtocounter{alphasect}{1}
  \fi%
\oldsection}%

\renewcommand\thesection{%
  \ifnum\alphainsection=1% 
    \Alph{alphasect}
  \else%
    \arabic{section}
  \fi%
}%

\newenvironment{alphasection}{%
  \ifnum\alphainsection=1%
    \errhelp={Let other blocks end at the beginning of the next block.}
    \errmessage{Nested Alpha section not allowed}
  \fi%
  \setcounter{alphasect}{0}
  \def\alphainsection{1}
}{%
  \setcounter{alphasect}{0}
  \def\alphainsection{0}
}%
```

**In document**:

```
\section{First test}
First content
\section{Second test}
Second content
\begin{alphasection}
\section{Third test}
\subsection{Subsection test}
Content test
\section{Test Other section}
\end{alphasection}
\section{Fourth test}
Last content
```

**Produces**:

```
1 First test
   First content

2 Second test
   Second content

A Third test
A.1 Subsection test
   Content test

B Test Other section

5 Fourth test
   Last content
```

**Tested, works with HyperRef.**

Comment: the problem is that for hyperref package *A* is the same as *1*, so links to *section 1* direct to *section A*

I need a command that will tell LaTeX to keep the original counter running but display different values (in my example - keep number 3 but display A and keep number 4 but display B)

Comment: @user309937 Fixed the problem ;) Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

to Sandra,
I had the spacing problem when using Pindatjuh code above. It was affecting all lists.
I fixed it adding "%" at the end of a couple of lines in the 3rd block of its code. Now I don't have the spacing anymore.

From:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{%
 \ifnum\alphainsection=1% 
   \Alph{alphasect}
 \else%
  \arabic{section}
 \fi%
}%
```

To:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{%
 \ifnum\alphainsection=1% 
   \Alph{alphasect}%
 \else
   \arabic{section}%
 \fi%
}%
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem Karpik had (problem with hyperref) could more easily be solved by adding the option [naturalnames] to the hyperref package:
`\usepackage[naturalnames]{hyperref}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solve it using @Pindatjuh code, solution is pretty ugly...

```
 \newcounter{alphasect}

 \renewcommand\thesection{%
 \ifnum\value{alphasect}=1%
A%%
 \else
\ifnum\value{alphasect}=2%
B%%
\else
\ifnum\value{alphasect}=3%
C%%
\else
\ifnum\value{alphasect}=4%
D%%
\else
 \arabic{section}%%
 \fi\fi\fi\fi}%

 \newenvironment{asection}{%
 \setcounter{alphasect}{1}%%
 }{%
 \setcounter{alphasect}{0}%%
 }%

 \newenvironment{bsection}{%
 \setcounter{alphasect}{2}%%
 }{%
 \setcounter{alphasect}{0}%%
 }%
```

a than in document:

```
\section{First test}
First content
\section{Second test}
Second content
\begin{asection}
\section{Third test}
\subsection{Subsection test}
Content test
\end{asection}
\begin{bsection}
\section{Test Other section}
\end{bsection}
\section{Fourth test}
Last content
```

now list of contents works, and it's displayed as it should

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package.